# My loop variable is not in accordance with HTML check box array variable

Tags: php, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNbFi.png)I have an array of check box that shows laboratory test names coming from a database. Whenever I retrieve them in PHP and display check box value along-with loop variable value ; they both contradict. When I choose third and fourth lab tests then loop variable should be like 2 and 3 but it is like 0 and 1

```html
    <?php
    $sql_lab = "SELECT * FROM lab_test WHERE is_del=0";
    $res_lab = mysql_query($sql_lab);
    while ($lab = mysql_fetch_array($res_lab)) {
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="lab_test[]" value="<?php echo   $lab['test_id']; ?>"/>
<?php echo $lab['test_type']; ?>
    <br/>

                                               
                                           
  <?php
} 
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['lab_test']); $i++) {
            if (isset($_POST['lab_test'][$i])) {
                
                echo $_POST['lab_test'][$i]."    ".$i."<br/>";

    }
    } 

?>
```

Comment: what is your issue? checkbox name is not print with checkbox?

Comment: Code looks fine, it seems i struggle to recognize the actual problem here.

Comment: print `$_POST['lab_test']` and paste it here

Comment: what is your problem here ?